# Disable all css animations in polymer

Tags: css, animation, polymer

I have a polymer web app with tons of css animations, all encapsulated inside different custom elements (using shadow dom).

I’d like to add an option for disabling all css animations.
Every component includes a shared style css document.

What’s the best practice for conditionally disable/enable all animations without editing each and every custom element? 
If I add the following css to the shared-styled doc then all animations are cancelled:

:host * { transition: none !important }

But I want to add it in case localstorage(“disableAnimations”) is true.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a behavior or mixin (depends on your polymer version) that observes the localStorage and if it has the value you expect you add the css line to your components.

Comment: Yep, this is the Polymer way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,body{
  
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0, height 0, top 0, left 0; 
}
```